# operator new not calling constructor

Tags: c++

Consider the belo code snippet:

```
class Base
{
    public:
    Base()
    {
            cout<<"Constructor"<<endl;
    }
    Base(const Base& rhs)
    {
            cout<<"Copy constructor"<<endl;
    }
    Base* Clone()
    {
            return new Base(*this); <--------------- 2
    }
    void* operator new(size_t size)
    {
            void* p=malloc(size);
            cout<<"Inside new"<<endl;
            return p;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base b1; <------------ 1
    Base* ptr=b1.Clone();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the [output](http://ideone.com/1oPTK) as:

```
Constructor
Inside new
Copy constructor
```

I kept hearing that first operator new allocates a chunk of void type & then new operator calls constructor to convert that chunk into the exact type as that on the LHS.
So, why the constructor is not getting called for statement 2?

I also want to know the exact series of actions undertaken by the C++ compiler for the statement 2.

Comment: Which constructor you expect to be called? The default one? `Clone` calls the copy-constructor, as you pass `*this` as argument.. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, why the constructor is not getting called for statement 2?

It is. Where do you think `"Copy constructor"` comes from?

```
Base b1;
```

Output: `Constructor`

```
Base* ptr=b1.Clone();
```

calls

```
new Base(*this);
```

which in turn calls your `operator new` and then your copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `T * p = new T(a, b, c); delete p;` is morally equivalent to this sequence:

```
void * const addr = operator new(sizeof T);   // either global or in T

T * p = new (addr) T(a, b, c);                // ditto

p->~T();

operator delete(addr);                        // ditto
```

The upshot is that memory allocation and object construction are two distinct concepts in C++.